# SQL(mysql) comparing times not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select the message from a row where the start and end time is the same as $a and $b. But it does not bring any results however when i remove the end time it brings all the results.

I dont understand why its not working.

```html
$a = '16:50:00';
$b = '17:00:00';
echo $times;

$query1 = ("SELECT message FROM db WHERE DATE(starttime) >= '$a' AND DATE(endtime) <= '$b'");
```

Comment: a little more context would go a long way in making your question more clear.

Comment: What is in the `starttime` and `endtime` columns? Just a time?

Comment: What is the datatype of `starttime` and `endtime`

Comment: Sorry the datatype is time

Comment: Then running `DATE()` on a time will return a DATE something like `2017-00-00` i.e. **nothing like a time**

Comment: Yeah its working my mistake, ill delete the question it was stupid sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say the `starttime` and `endtime` columns are of type TIME. Running a DATE() on them will really mess the time up.

```
SELECT DATE('17:00:00);
```

will return `2017-00-00` i.e the best date it can make out of a time. Which of course is no use to you at all.

So mod your query to

```
SELECT message FROM db WHERE starttime >= '$a' AND endtime <= '$b'
```